# Async timeout: Task.WhenAny() when I have Awaiter rather than Task

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, asynchronous, async-await

I'm somewhat new to async C#, and I'm dealing with a class which has an `Awaiter` but no `Task`. (It's Unity 3D's `WWW` class, and I'm using [these extension classes](http://www.stevevermeulen.com/index.php/2017/09/using-async-await-in-unity3d-2017/) to provide `WWW.GetAwaiter()`.)

I want to impose a timeout for the `await`, after which I'll continue the function's logic, taking a different code path because I'll know the awaiter took too long. The intuitive solution is:

```
Task timeout = Task.Delay(20*1000);
await Task.WhenAny(wwwTask, timeout);
bool timedOut = !wwwTask.IsCompleted;
```

Since `WWW` is a custom class (with `GetAwaiter()`) and not a task, I need to make a task for this to work. Is making a helper function the right way to get a task for that object?

```
private async Task<WWW> SendRequestAsync(WWW www)
{
    return await www;
}
```

And to get the task:

```
Task wwwTask = SendRequestAsync(www);
```

Is this timeout logic sound, and is it the easiest way to work with Tasks when there is only an awaiter?

Comment: Yep, writing a simple helper function is the simplest thing to do here. Let the compiler do the work.

Comment: You better test the result of `WhenAny`: it returns the **first** completed task, and you're checking the started one, which can complete after the check: `var result = await Task.WhenAny(wwwTask, timeout); if (result != timeout) {/* DO THE CODE HERE */ }`

Comment: @VMAtm Thanks for the info! However, in this case it's more useful to check the result afterwards. If the request competes after the timeout but before I check the result, it's an unexpected bonus, not a bug.

Comment: @VMAtm Would you say the situation I mentioned ("bonus" task completion) will realistically never happen, and checking `result == timeout` is more efficient than checking if the task is done?

Comment: As far as I know, this is usual way to check the timeout task

Answer (score 1):

To return a task with generic change your code:

```
private async Task<WWW> SendRequestAsync(WWW www)
{
    return await www;
}
```

to

```
private async Task<WWW> SendRequestAsync(WWW www)
{
    return Task.FromResult(www);
}
```

Comment: But aren't those two functions different? The first returns a task which waits for `www.GetAwaiter()` to complete. The second returns a task which is already complete. And as such, the second one can't be an `async` function.

Comment: And in addition to not compiling, the second function doesn't make sense. `Task.FromResult` doesn't wait for any completion. It immediately returns a completed task.